# How to extract top-left and bottom-right coordinates from bounds value

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to extract the X and Y coordinates of the top-right & bottom-left of a text box given the value of the bound.

Example: `[84,672][1356,889]`

Is there a quick and easy function available in JavaScript that would extract the above values into two separate variables so that I can then calculate the center coordinates?
Like:

```
A = [84,672]
B = [1356,889]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RegEx:

```js
const input = "[84,672][1356,889]";

// parse input
const nums = input.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
const A = [nums[0], nums[1]];
const B = [nums[2], nums[3]];

console.log(A, B);

// calculate midpoint
const mdpt = [(A[0]+B[0])/2, (A[1]+B[1])/2];
console.log(mdpt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert your string into a [valid JSON string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) so that:

```js
"[84,672][1356,889]"
```

becomes

```
"[[84,672],[1356,889]]"
```

You can do this by replacing `][` with `], [` and wrapping your string in`[]`. Then you can [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) this string into a JavaScript array, and use indexing to extract the values into variables:

```js
const A = arr[0];
const B = arr[1];
```

Or you can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as shown below to extract the nested arrays into variables

```js
const str = "[84,672][1356,889]";
const [A, B] = JSON.parse(`[${str.replaceAll("][", "],[")}]`);

console.log(A);
console.log(B);
```

Note: If you can't support [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), you can use a global regular expression with the [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method instead: `.replace(/]\[/g, '],[')`

Answer (score -1):

There is no quick and simple single function that will do that, no. But you can use simple string functions to make your own:

Here I used [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

As the result was an array, I used [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert the original strings to numbers, and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the results.

```js
const input = "[84,672][1356,889]";

function extractCoordinates(input) {
  // get a and b as strings using indexOf with offset
  const aStr = input.substring(0, input.indexOf('[', 1));
  const bStr = input.substring(input.indexOf('[', 1), input.length);
  // create a function that will remove the brackets and coerce to a number
  const mapToNumber = (s) => +s.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');
  // split the strings on the comma and run the function on the parts
  const a = aStr.split(',').map(mapToNumber);
  const b = bStr.split(',').map(mapToNumber);
  // And that's it
  return [a, b];
}

// Here I use array destructuring to get the results:
const [a, b] = extractCoordinates(input);
console.log(a, b);
```